# Htaccess: redirect to first or only file at directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with a structure created by users depending content. That structure is something like this:

- www.domain.com/
- www.domain.com/vehicles/
- www.domain.com/vehicles/vehicles.html
- www.domain.com/vehicles/cars/
- www.domain.com/vehicles/cars/cars_x.html
- www.domain.com/vehicles/bikes/
- www.domain.com/vehicles/bikes/bikes_new.html
- www.domain.com/vehicles/bus/
- www.domain.com/vehicles/bus/bus_big.html

Site is working properly, well seo indexed but sometimes, users or visitors write down wrong addresses like www.domain.com/vehicles/cars or www.domain.com/vehicles/cars/ and that returns a 404 page not found or 403 directory listing forbidden.

Its possible (with htaccess) to tell apache to get the first or only html file on directory if directory exists by default? in pseudocode

if www.domain.com/vehicles/cars is directory
and www.domain.com/vehicles/cars has not default page (index.html/index.php)
get 1st/only .html file at directory for serving it.

bts, its not possible to create or add an index.html/index.php in every directory due its dinamically created by editors and they decide the file names.

Thanks!